# Communicate with Worker Role from Web Site

Tags: azure

Microsoft says [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/) that Web Sites can be combined with Worker Roles in Cloud Services. However internal endpoints of Worker Roles only allow access from within the boundaries of the Cloud Service. How do you securely (privately) communicate with a Worker Role that is an internal part of the architecture? Is message queues the recommended way or is there something like security groups as in aws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Roles (PaaS) can be combined with Worker Roles (also PaaS). Azure Web Sites however, are not PaaS Cloud Services and therefore can't connect to the internal endpoint of a Worker Role.

Your options are:
a) created an input endpoint for the worker role and implement proper authentication on any in-bound service calls. 
b) leverage a intermediary such as queues or service bus to handle authentication of requests
c) convert your Azure Web Site to a Web Role and leverage the internal endpoints.

The path I would investigate first would be leveraging either service bus queues or storage queues. Just be aware of the limits of each and make sure they will meet your needs. This should prove helpful in understanding the differences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx